# I was tasked with installing a bitcoin core on ubuntu and I had questions

Tags: bitcoin-core

I was given the task to install Bitcoin core, to receive payments in the service. I have found some tutorials, but they were not used because they are GUIs. I want to use a bitcoin from the command line. How do i install bitcoin bark? How much free memory do you need?

Comment: What is Bitcoin Bark? Is it Bitcoin Core?

Answer (score 2):

At least 1 GB of ram is needed. If that is not enough you can simply add some swap memory to build the daemon.
Disk space is required also and at the time of writing it is around 200 GB.

**To Build**

```
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
make install # optional
```

**Required dependencies**

*Ubuntu & Debian*

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libtool autotools-dev automake pkg-config bsdmainutils python3
```

Now, you can either build from self-compiled depends or install the required dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev libevent-dev libboost-system-dev libboost-filesystem-dev libboost-chrono-dev libboost-test-dev libboost-thread-dev
```

*BerkeleyDB is required for the wallet.*

For Ubuntu only: db4.8 packages are available here. You can add the repository and install using the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bitcoin/bitcoin
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libdb4.8-dev libdb4.8++-dev
```

Ubuntu and Debian have their own libdb-dev and libdb++-dev packages, but these will install BerkeleyDB 5.1 or later. This will break binary wallet compatibility with the distributed executables, which are based on BerkeleyDB 4.8. If you do not care about wallet compatibility, *pass --with-incompatible-bdb to configure.*

*To build Bitcoin Core without wallet, see Disable-wallet mode*

Optional (see --with-miniupnpc and --enable-upnp-default):

```
sudo apt-get install libminiupnpc-dev
```

ZMQ dependencies (provides ZMQ API):

```
sudo apt-get install libzmq3-dev
```

source: [bitcoin github](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/build-unix.md)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple step-by-step HOWTO on downloading, building, and upgrading bitcoin core. I’ve tested this on recent Ubuntu, Debian, and Raspbian distros.

https://github.com/alevchuk/minibank/blob/master/bitcoin/README.md

Yet, allow 5 to 10 days for bitcoin to download the block chain. That time depends on the speed of your internet connection.

As far as RAM, 1GB is a safe number.  I was able to run it at 433 MB Razpbeerry Pi Zero and Amazon AWS. Yet, that needs another 600 MB of swap. There are some considerations what using swap, read a note about swap here https://github.com/alevchuk/minibank/blob/master/README.md#memory